# glb/gltf export when previewed has rotated textures

Tags: texturing, uv, image, gltf

I've made a simple Blender model using image textures and some manually UV unwrapping. I'm representing these as a Prinicpled BSDF with an image texture and some bump mapping. When I export the model to a .glb file and open in with , or any online GLTF previewer, my textures are rotated (it seems by 90 degrees). Is there a way to "bake in" the right image orientation?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you share the blend file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Keep in mind the glTF file can't store native Blender nodes.  The exporter must interpret the nodes it finds in your graph, and figure out how best to represent them in glTF.  There are instructions here:  https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/import_export/scene_gltf2.html